# Two flask apps using one database

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Hello I don't think this is in the right place for this question but I don't know where to ask it. I want to make a website and an api for that website using the same SQLAlchemy database would just running them at the same time independently be safe or would this cause corruption from two write happening at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

SQLA *is* a python wrapper for SQL. It is *not* it's own database. If you're running your website (perhaps flask?) and managing your api from the same script, you can simply use the same **reference** to your **instance** of SQLA. Meaning, when you use SQLA to connect to a database and save to a variable, what is really happening is it saves the *connection* to a variable, and you continually reference that variable, as opposed to the more inefficient method of creating a new connection every time. So when you say

> using the same SQLAlchemy database

I believe you are actually referring to the actual underlying database itself, not the SQLA wrapper/connection to it.

If your website and API are not running in the same script (or even if they are, depending on how your API handles simultaneous requests), you may encounter a *race condition*, which, [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition), is defined as:

> the condition of an electronics, software, or other system where the system's substantive behavior is dependent on the sequence or timing of other uncontrollable events. It becomes a bug when one or more of the possible behaviors is undesirable.

This may be what you are referring to when you mentioned

> would this cause corruption from two write happening at the same time.

To avoid such situations, when a process accesses a file, (depending on the OS,) check is performed to see if there is a "lock" on that file, and if so, the OS refuses to open that file. A lock is created when a process accesses a file (and there is no other process holding a lock on that file), such as by using `with open(filename):` and is released when the process no longer holds an open reference to the file (such as when python execution leaves the `with open(filename):` indentation block.) This may be the real issue you might encounter when using two simultaneous connections to a SQLite db.

However, if you are using something like MySQL, where you connect to a SQL **server process**, and **NOT** a file, since there is no direct access to a file, there will be no lock on the database, and you may run in to that nasty race condition in the following **made up** scenario:

1. Stack Overflow queries the reputation an account to see if it should be banned due to negative reputation.
2. **AT THE EXACT SAME TIME**, Someone upvotes an answer made by that account that sets it one point under the account ban threshold.
3. The outcome is now determined by the speed of execution of these 2 tasks.

If the upvoter has, say, a slow computer, and the "upvote" does not get processed by StackOverflow before the reputation query completes, the account will be banned. However, if there is some lag on Stack Overflow's end, and the upvote processes before the account query finishes, the account will not get banned.

The key concept behind this example is that all of these steps can occur within fractions of a second, and the outcome depends of the speed of execution on both ends.

To address the issue of data corruption, most databases have a system in place that properly order database read and writes, however, there are still semantic issues that may arise, such as the example given above.

Answer (score 0):

Two applications can use the same database as the DB is a separate application that will be accessed by each flask app.

What you are asking can be done and is the methodology used by many large web applications, specially when the API is written in a different framework than the main application.

Since SQL databases are ACID compliant, they have a system in place to queue the multiple read/write requests put to it and perform them in the correct order while ensuring data reliability.

One question to ask though is whether it is useful to write two separate applications. For most flask-only projects the best approach would be to separate the project using blueprints, having a “main” blueprint and a “api” blueprint.